# Why do not symbol conflict when contain same static library?

Tags: xcode, linker, static-libraries

There is static library name `libstatic1.a`, another static library named `libstatic2.a`  test app named `testapp`

`libstatic1.a` has a method `testcmethds`

`libstatic2.a` linked `libstatic1.a`, and called `testcmethds` in method `samecalltest`

`testapp` linked `libstatic1.a` and `libstatic2.a`

`testapp` will complie successfully and normal running.

Why there didn't have symbol conflict, i use `nm -a` to check two `.a` lib, it have same method symbol.

```
//in libstatic1.a
//...
0000000000000000 T _testcmethds
//...

//in libstatic2.a
//...
0000000000000000 T _testcmethds
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why there didn't have symbol conflict

There isn't a conflict because the linker never pulls in the object containing `_testcmethds` from `libstatic2.a` into the link.

To understand this better, read [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking/) or [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

Note: the design in which the same global symbol(s) appear in multiple libraries is exceedingly fragile. A day will come when you'll regret designing things that way.